# jQuery .focus() causes page to jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that should scroll a user back to a search input at the top of the page, and **then** place focus on it (so the cursor is blinking). For some reason, it seems to apply the focus to the search input first. This creates a very quick jump/spazzy movement of the page to the search bar, jumps back to the bottom, and then scrolls up slowly.

The Javascript:

```
function goToSearch(){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#search').offset().top},'medium');
    $('#search').focus()
}
```

The HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="search">
...
<a href="#" onclick="goToSearch()">Search</a>
```

I've tried setting .delay() functions to no avail; it seems to always apply the .focus() first. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> *"Why is this happening?"*

The animation effect is asynchronous. That is, the `.animate()` function returns *immediately* after "scheduling" the animation (so to speak) and execution continues immediately with the next statement - in your case, the `.focus()` statement. The actual animation will take place after the current JS completes.

Fortunately the [`.animate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) provides an option for you to pass a callback function that will be called when the animation is complete, so you can do the focus within that callback function:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#search').offset().top},'medium', function(){
    $('#search').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You should call the focus function when the animation is complete, like so:

```
function goToSearch(){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#search').offset().top},'medium',function(){
        $('#search').focus();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you found this question like me, you were probably looking for a CSS related issue coupled with the js focus() and you might think you're out of luck. Well, think again - the good news is that there IS a way to have a callback when a CSS animation or transition ends and then fire your event.

You can make use of jQuery's [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method and use either `webkitTransitionEnd` `otransitionend` `oTransitionEnd` `msTransitionEnd` `transitionend` for transitions or `webkitAnimationEnd` `oanimationend` `msAnimationEnd` `animationend` for animations.

**An example:**

*JS:*

```
var myButton = $('#button'),
   myBox = $('#box');
    myButton.click(function () { 
    myBox.addClass('change-size');
    myBox.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',   
    function(e) {
    // code to execute after animation ends
    myBox.removeClass('change-size');
    });

});
```

*CSS:*

```
.box {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: hotpink;
}

@keyframes growBox {
    to {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
    }
}

.change-size {
    animation: growBox 3s linear 0s 1 normal;
}
```

The solution is not mine, I just found it after a couple of wasted hours, and I'm posting it in case you find this question first.

Source: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end